# using C struct that is declared later

Tags: c, coding-style, typedef, forward-declaration

I want use a typedef struct that isn't already defined, but it is later.
Is there anything like a struct prototype?

file container.h

```
// i would place a sort of struct prototype here
typedef struct 
{
 TheType * the_type;
} Container;
```

file thetype.h

```
typedef struct {......} TheType;
```

file main.c

```
#include "container.h"
#include "thetype.h"
...
```

Comment: Not sure what of the relationship you're trying to establish between TheType and Container.  What is it specifically you are asking?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus he's wanting to "forward declare a `typedef`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
// i would place a sort of struct prototype here
```

with these lines:

```
struct TheType;
typedef struct TheType TheType;
```

Since you need the type `TheType` to be defined before type `Container` is defined, you have to use forward declaration of type `TheType` - and to do so you also need forward declaration of struct `TheType`.

Then you will not define typedef `TheType` like this:

```
typedef struct {......} TheType;
```

but you will define struct `TheType`:

```
struct {......};
```

Answer (score 5):

In container.h:

```
struct _TheType;
typedef struct _TheType TheType;
```

Than in thetype.h:

```
struct _TheType { ..... };
```

Comment: This is the correct answer; for the OP's further illumination, what is being done here is called a "forward declaration".

Comment: identifiers that begin with an `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved identifiers

Comment: Sorry. I recalled the rule being somewhat different.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a struct inside the typedef:

```
typedef struct TheType_Struct TheType;  // declares "struct TheType_Struct"
                                        // and makes typedef
typedef struct
{
    TheType * p;
} UsefulType;
```

Note though that you may only have [at most one `typedef` in one translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594954/repeated-typedefs-invalid-in-c-but-valid-in-c) in C89 and C99 (this differs from C11 and C++).

Later on you must define the actual `struct TheType_Struct { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define an object of an, as yet, undefined `struct`; but you can define a pointer to such a `struct`

```
struct one {
    struct undefined *ok;
    // struct undefined obj; /* error */
};

int foo(void) {
  volatile struct one obj;
  obj.ok = 0;               /* NULL, but <stddef.h> not included, so 0 */
  if (obj.ok) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

The above *module* is legal (and compiles with gcc without warnings).