# Why can't redefine type names in class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, scope, typename

According to the book C++ Primer section, 7.4.1 Type Names Are Special:

> Ordinarily, an inner scope can redefine a name from an outer scope even if that name has already been used in the inner scope. However, in a class, if a member uses a name from an outer scope and that name is a type, then the class may not subsequently redefine that name.

Accordingly, for example:

```
typedef double Money;
class Account {
    public:
        Money balance() { return bal; }
    private:
        typedef double Money;
        Money bal;
};

int main() {
    typedef double Money;
    Money asset;
    typedef double Money;
    return 0;
}
```

When you compile the example above, it will complain:

```
a.cc:6:24: error: declaration of ‘typedef double Account::Money’ [-fpermissive]
         typedef double Money;
                        ^
a.cc:1:16: error: changes meaning of ‘Money’ from ‘typedef double Money’ [-fpermissive]
 typedef double Money;
```

So why can not we redefine type names in class, but can we in the inner scope?

---

My compiler version is `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`.
And there is also a note in that section:

> Although it is an error to redefine a type name, compilers are not required to diagnose this error. Some compilers will quietly accept such code, even though the program is in error.

Comment: What if you changed the order of the lines in `main` to have the `typedef` after the `Money asset`?

Comment: @Justin, it is ok in `main` function though changing the order of the lines.

Comment: That can make for some interesting error messages: https://wandbox.org/permlink/N918N1IqbP2E5g0O . I guess it's just not prohibited for inside functions, but it is for inside classes

Comment: @Justin, my compiler is `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`.

Comment: @user4581301. If moving the `typedef` up above the method declaration, it works. But I still can't understand the reason?

Comment: Classes are kind of funny. You know how you can use a member variable that hasn't been defined yet in a method? If you have a disconnect in types between that member variable and the method, that's gotta be a real head-trip for the poor compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not unique to types. [basic.class.scope]/2:

> A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its
>   context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

The reason is that name lookup in class scope is a little special. Consider:

```
using Foo = int;

struct X {
    Foo a;    // ::Foo, i.e., int
    void meow() { 
        Foo b = a; // X::Foo; error: no conversion from int to char*
    }
    using Foo = char*;
};
```

Name lookup in member function bodies considers all class members, whether declared before or after the member function (otherwise, a member function defined in a class definition wouldn't be able to use a data member declared later in the class). The result is that you get two `Foo`s with different meanings, even though they both lexically precede the class member `Foo`'s declaration. This can easily lead to extremely confusing and brittle code, and so the standard bans it.

Comment: So, in this example, two `Foo`s with different meaning both lexically precede the statement `Foo b = a` in function `meow`. Then *the compiler can't determine which the type of b is*. Is it correct or not?

Comment: This answer is a great example.

Answer (score 3):

When the compiler reads the line

```
    Money balance() { return bal; }
```

in the class definition, it already uses the definition of `Money` outside the class. That makes the line

```
    typedef double Money;
```

inside the class a problem. However, you may use redefine `Money` inside the class before it is used in the class. The following is OK.

```
typedef double Money;

class Account {
    public:
        typedef double Money;
        Money balance() { return bal; }
    private:
        Money bal;
};
```

The key point in the quote is:

> hence the class may not **subsequently** redefine that name.

Comment: But in the function `main`, we can redefine `typedef double Money` even if it is defined after the statement `Money asset`.

Comment: I want to know is that why "the class may not subsequently redefine that name." But "an inner scope can redefine a name from an outer scope *even if that name has already been used in the inner scope*."

Answer (score 2):

I would like to try to answer some questions from your comments.

**Comment 1**

> "But in the function main, we can redefine typedef double Money even if it is defined after the statement Money asset"

So you are asking, why `typedef` identifier can be defined more than once in a non-member function(in a non-class scope)?

The answer is here:[Repeated typedefs - invalid in C but valid in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594954/repeated-typedefs-invalid-in-c-but-valid-in-c)

**Comment 2**

> So, in this example, two Foos with different meaning both lexically precede the statement Foo b = a in function meow. Then the compiler can't determine which the type of b is. Is it correct or not?

The complier can determine the type of b in that code chunk. B's type is obvisouly `char*` while the type of a is `int`.

Although two `Foo` with different meaning both lexically precede the statement `Foo b = a` in function `meow`, `Foo` defined as `int` precedes `Foo` defined as `char*`. The book says that the **name lookup** process is different:

> • First, the member declarations are compiled.
>   • Function bodies are compiled only after the entire class has been seen.

So in the first step, while compiling member declarations,
`Foo a` and `using Foo = char*` get compiled **in order**. And the first `Foo` uses outside definition of `Foo`, which is `int`. Then, an inner scope `Foo` is created, with type `char*`. After that, the compiler starts to compile the function body. For function `meow`, `Foo b` uses inner scope `Foo`, which is `char*`, while for `a`, which is already get compiled in the first step, is a int `Foo`. So that's how the **conversion error** occurs.

**Comment 3**

> I want to know is that why "the class may not subsequently redefine that name." But "an inner scope can redefine a name from an outer scope even if that name has already been used in the inner scope." –

**R Sahu**'s point (and I think it is what the book wants to say) is that **if you really want to redefine a `typedef` identifier, you can only do this in the very beginning of your class. So there won't be any "ambiguity" about that identifier among the context.**

**Summary**:

Allow this:

(**This can't compile in g++ (because standard ban this) but can in Visual Studio, because logically there's no conflict here.**)

```
typedef double Money;
class Account {
    public:
        Money balance() { return bal; }
    private:
        typedef double Money;
        Money bal;
};
```

is very easy to cause things like this:

(**can't compile in both g++ and Visual Studio, because logically there is  conflict here.**)

```
using Foo = int;

struct X {
    Foo a;    // ::Foo, i.e., int
    void meow() { 
        Foo b = a; // X::Foo; error: no conversion from int to char*
    }
    using Foo = char*;
};
```

so if you really want to redefine a `typedef` identifier inside a class. Only do this:

(**can compile in both g++ and Visual Studio, because logically there's no conflict here and standard only allows this.**)

```
typedef double Money;

class Account {
    public:
        typedef double Money;  
        //put the redefine statement in the very beginning
        Money balance() { return bal; }
    private:
        Money bal;
};
```

**PS:**

**Explain the code**:

```
typedef double Money;
class Account {
    public:
        Money balance() { return bal; }
    private:
        typedef double Money;
        Money bal;
};
```

These code is **logically** right but **for standard** it is banned. Same compiling step as mentioned above, first compile function `balance`'s declaration, so `Money` here is the outside `Money`. Then complie `typedef double Money` we get a inner scope `Money` and the type of `bal` is `Account::Money` not the outside one.

So practically you can do this with **Visual Studio** compiler but not with **g++**:

```
typedef double Money;
class Account {
    public:
        Money shit = 12.34; //outside money, type is double
    private:
        typedef string Money;  
        Money bal;   //bal is string not double
};
```

Thanks for the enlightenment from the other two answers. And there's some prediction in my post which is my personal deduction. If there's anything wrong, feel free to correct it.