# Is it legal to redefine a type name?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, typespec

Chapter 7.4.1 of the book C++ Primer says the following:

> Ordinarily, an inner scope can redefine a name from an outer scope even if that name has already been used in the inner scope. However, in a class, if a member uses a name from an outer scope and that name is a type, then the class may not subsequently redefine that name

The word *subsequently* makes me think that it is only an error to redefine a type name after it has been used in the class. However, two paragraphs later it says:

> Although it is an error to redefine a type name, compilers are not required to diagnose this error.

Does this mean that it is an error to redefine a type name even before it has been used in a class?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384956/why-cant-redefine-type-names-in-class-in-c?

Comment: No, there is a subtle difference. My question is wether it is legal to redefine a type name before it has been used in a class.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the quote refers to the following case

```
typedef int T;

struct A
{
    T a[10];
    typedef double T;
};
```

That is the code is ill-formed due to the redeclaration of the name `T` within the class definition that was already used in the declaration of the data member `a`.

If you will just write

```
typedef int T;

struct A
{
    int a[10];
    typedef double T;
};
```

then this code is correct. The name `T` is not used as a type specifier in declarations of members of the class A.

Comment: Alright, so the second quote is too general, and it does matter wether the type has been used in the class before the redeclaration? Is this in the standard?

Comment: @L.S.Roth There are many cases in the C++ Standard when compilers are not required to issue an error for an ill-formed code. So one compiler can compile an ill-formed code successfully and you will think that it is correct while other compiler will issue an error for such a code.

Answer (score 3):

The OP writes in the comment section:

> ... My question is wether [*sic*] it is legal to redefine a type name before it has been used in a class.

The answer is yes. It is legal to define a type name in a class that shadows a type name in an enclosing scope. What is not allowed is the following:

- A name, call it `T` (though it need not be a type), is used inside a class, and name lookup finds some declaration `D`, and
- The class declares a member named `T`, and
- After the class has been completely defined, if the compiler goes back and parses the previous use of the name `T`, it now finds the new member declaration *instead of* `D`.

Let's go over a few examples to clarify the issue.

```
using T = X;
class C {
    using T = Y;
    T x;
};
```

The above example is legal because when the compiler sees `T x;`, it has already seen `using T = Y;`, so `T` can only resolve to `Y`. There are no subsequent declarations inside the class that can change the meaning later.

```
using T = X;
class C {
    T x;
    using T = Y;
};
```

The above example is illegal. The compiler at first looks up `T` and finds the enclosing definition of `T` as `X`, since `C::T` hasn't been declared yet. But after `C::T` has been declared, it implies that if `T x;` were to be reinterpreted, then `T` would now refer to `C::T` instead, since the class scope takes precedence over the enclosing scope.

```
using T = ::X;
class C {
    T x;
    using T = ::X;
};
```

The above example is illegal. The fact that both declarations of `T` make it refer to the same type is not relevant. The violation occurs because `T x;` would find a *different declaration* of `T` after the class is completely defined.

```
using T = X;
class C {
    ::T x;
    using T = Y;
};
```

The above example is legal. The declaration `using T = Y;` does not change the meaning of `::T`, because `::T` will always refer to the global declaration even though `C::T` is there.

```
using T = X;
class C {
    void foo() { T x; }
    using T = Y;
};
```

The above example is legal. The body of `foo` is a *complete-class context*, which implies that name lookup for `T` is not done until after the entire class has been seen. Put another way, the declaration `using T = Y;` in a sense always "precedes" the body of `foo` so this is similar to the first example.